# Windows 10: Setup Face Sign-in

Tags: windows-10, login

I have read that Windows 10 allows face sign-in.

When I search for it in the start menu, it comes up:

[image]

But there are no relevant settings on the screen that pops up:

[image]

How do I enable it?  If relevant, my computer is on an ADDS domain (that I control).

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Hello](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt450467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) requires specific technology in the camera before it appears as an option.

Supported cameras have an IR (infrared) sensor.  Without this, you could just hold up a picture of the person authorised to login - a photo doesn't emit IR, whereas a human face does.  IR also works well in different visible light conditions, even darkness.